# Support for .NET 4.6.2 in Azure Web Job

Tags: .net, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service, .net-4.6.2

I tried deploying an Azure Web App built against .NET Framework 4.6.2 and it seems to work fine. However, within the same app, if I deploy a web job built against .NET 4.6.2, then it does not work. I get the following error:

```
[10/06/2016 19:42:25 > b29283: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[10/06/2016 19:42:27 > b29283: SYS INFO] Run script 'Run.ps1' with script host - 'PowerShellScriptHost'
[10/06/2016 19:42:27 > b29283: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[10/06/2016 19:42:31 > b29283: INFO] Web job execution failed. Error code: -2146232576
[10/06/2016 19:42:31 > b29283: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[10/06/2016 19:42:31 > b29283: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -1
```

Run.ps1 looks as follows:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
& "$PSScriptRoot\ConsoleApplication1.exe"
if ($lastexitcode -ne 0)
{
    Write-Output "Web job execution failed. Error code: $lastexitcode"
    exit -1
}
```

ConsoleApplication1.exe just prints a line to console:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from .NET 4.6.2");
        }
    }
}
```

When will the support for .NET framework 4.6.2 be added to Azure web jobs?

Comment: Did you mean a lower fx version in the case that worked? Might want to fix that in your question.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Sorry, didn't get that.

Comment: Sorry, it was me misreading you question :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a console application using .NET Framework v4.6.2 and publish it as WebJob, and same issue appears on my side, the execution fails. So I guess that currently Azure WebJob does not support .NET Framework v4.6.2. As a workaround, you could try to modify [`<supportedRuntime>` element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68(v=vs.110).aspx) sku attribute in configuration file.

```
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
</startup>
```

Besides, you could give a feedback like [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/11070060-webjobs-executables-fail-when-targeting-net-4-6-1).

Comment: That's correct, we don't support 4.6.2 yet. This should happen later this month.

Comment: Hi David, what version does Azure App Service (Web App) support now? 4.6.1? 4.6?

Comment: As far as I know, it supports v4.6.1.

Comment: Is .Net 4.6.2 supported now for WebJobs on Azure?

Comment: @Sam Yes, it has been for a while now.